# Postgres Datasource Definition - connection refused

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, datasource

I'm trying to set up a quick datasource which will be used for integration tests, so rather than configuring it on the app server - Wildfly 10 - I'd prefer to deploy it on the fly.

This is how I configured it:

```
@DataSourceDefinitions({
    @DataSourceDefinition(
            name = "java:/datasources/testdb",
            className = "org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource",
            user = "testdb",
            password = "testdb",
            serverName = "localhost",
            portNumber = 5432,
            databaseName = "testdb",
            minPoolSize = 10,
            maxPoolSize = 50)
})
public class DatasourceDefinitions {}
```

I've tried with `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and using the parameter `url` instead of the triple `serverName`, `port` and `databaseName`, but I always run into a `Connection Refused` error

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:62)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:76)
    ... 41 more
```

I have already checked `user` and `password` and they work just fine if I try to log in with `pgAdmin`.

Here is Postgres configuration:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

I also enabled the line

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

in the configuration file `postgresql.conf`

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing and/or doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the normal postgres driver class.

Comment: @ManoDestra nope.... `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.Driver cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was in `Postgres` configuration, namely in file `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf`.

I changed this

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost'
```

into this

```
listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1'
```

and now it works perfectly.